# How to read input data from pinpad using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

Thank you in advance for all your suggestions or inputs.
I am building a POC where I need to read data from pinpad . 
When user swipes the card or enter the data on the pinpad my application is supposed to read the card details in an encrypted manner. 
I need to read card number, name and pin entered.

Could anyone please help on the kind of approach I need to follow in order to read the data from pinpad.

Thanks,
Satish